# Why use plutonium when sunlight is everywhere? Any proposals to use concentrated solar power instead of Pu238 as a heat source for TGs?

Tags: solar-power, jupiter, saturn, rtg, inflatable

Why use plutonium when sunlight is everywhere? The case for powering thermoelectric generators (TG) with concentrated solar rather than plutonium:

> Spacecraft operating in the inner Solar System usually rely on the use
> of … photovoltaic (PV) solar panels to derive electricity from sunlight.
> Outside the orbit of Jupiter, solar radiation is too weak to produce
> sufficient power within current solar technology and spacecraft mass
> limitations, so radioisotope thermoelectric generators (RTGs) are
> instead used as a power source.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_panels_on_spacecraft

Solar flux falls with the square of the distance from the Sun. For space exploration in the inner solar system, solar flux is high enough for solar PV.

For more distant voyages (i.e.: beyond Jupiter), RTGs take over. For instance, LUCY has solar arrays for working at Jupiter distance, while Cassini used RTGs in its Saturn voyage.

An alternative to RGTs is to use solar concentrators paired with solar Thermoelectric Generators (TG)

TGs are solid state generators which convert heat directly to electricity with no moving parts.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator

The "R" in RTGs is usually plutonium as a heat source. TGs will also work with sources of heat other than radioactive decay, such as solar. [https://www.nrel.gov/csp/facility-hfsf.html#:~:text=The%20solar%20furnace%20can%20quickly,up%20to%203%2C000%C2%B0](https://www.nrel.gov/csp/facility-hfsf.html#:%7E:text=The%20solar%20furnace%20can%20quickly,up%20to%203%2C000%C2%B0) .

Most current RTGs operate at over 1000C. Solar TGs would need a solar concentrator to produce temperatures in this range.

High performance TGs can attain efficiencies of over 30%, which is similar to the  photovoltaic (PV) panels on the ISS. However, this is an apples-and-oranges comparison since TGs can use a larger portion of the solar spectrum than PV. And PV performance is actually reduced by the heat produced from the thermal part of the solar spectrum.

[image]

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283471128_Spectrum_splitting_for_eicient_utilization_of_solar_radiation_a_novel_photovoltaic-thermoelectric_power_generation_system

PV cells use only about half of the light spectrum provided by the sun. The infrared part is not utilized to produce electricity. Instead, the infrared light heats up the PV cells and thereby decreases the efficiency of the cell.

A solar concentrator can be created with single layer of aluminized Mylar. Using an inflated structure, the mass per area of the reflector could be very low. Below is a picture of the 30m Echo satellite. The launch mass of the satellite was 180Kg, or 250 grams per square meter of cross sectional area.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Echo

[image]

As an example, the 1.1m long RTG  generator used in the Galileo spacecraft  (drawing below)  had a TG with a surface area of about 0.16m^2. If the light from a 6m solar collector at Saturn’s orbital distance is focused on a 0.16m^2 TG target, the solar flux would be the same as planet Mercury where daytime temperatures are 800F (700K).

[image]

This implies that a solar TG with an 8m reflector at Saturn orbital distance would out-generate the RTG used in Galileo.

Plutonium costs about $9,600,000/Kg to produce. That is 75,000,000 clams per RTG. Cassini had 3 of them. https://www.forbes.com/sites/williampentland/2015/11/08/peak-plutonium-238-u-s-starts-making-nuclear-fuel-for-deep-space-missions/?sh=3be1744b53b4

Since RTGs have limitations due to longevity, cost and safety, have there been any proposals to use concentrated solar power as a heat source for TGs in exploration of the outer solar system?

More to read: [What is the status of concentrated solar energy (CSE) in space exploration?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-is-the-status-of-concentrated-solar-energy-cse-in-space-exploration)

Comment: While looking for sources, I found this wild [solar-thermal propulsion spacecraft proposal](https://www.autoevolution.com/news/ussf-to-conquer-deep-space-with-groundbreaking-solar-thermal-powered-spacecraft-165593.html). I think solar thermoelectric systems ultimately have lower volume and mass efficiency than photovoltaic, and concentrated solar-thermal steam turbines are mass prohibitive, but I need to dig some more to back that up.

Comment: different but related to solar concentrators: [Why did Deep Space 1 use solar concentrators?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34119/12102) and [Were solar concentrators on HS-702 just a stop-gap measure until triple-junction PV cells were available?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21410/12102) and [Hows does "Glenn Research Center's sapphire refractive secondary concentrator" work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30231/12102)

Comment: One big advantage of RTGs is that they work even when there is no sun, be it due to clouds, night, or the sun being eclipsed by an orbiting planet/moon

Comment: @ErinAnne ... Think that's a weird rocket? Check this oddball solar thermal rocket some nut thought up: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/could-a-solar-gravitational-synchrotron-use-solar-thermal-rockets-to-powersl

Comment: A solar concentrator built of a single layer of aluminized Mylar as an inflated structure, could be destroyed by a tiny micrometeorite. The concentrator should not change its shape when loosing the gas pressure.

Comment: @Uwe ...  https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2005ESASP.581E..97L deals with pre-preg materials which cure in solar UV after deployment. Once cured, they maintain rigidity if de-pressurized.

Comment: But this pre-preg material is not a single layer of aluminized Mylar only.

Comment: Solar electric arcjet or resistojet rockets with water as the reaction mass seem to offer possibilities.

Comment: @KenFabian ... direct solar thermal propulsion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_thermal_rocket ) skips the electricity and may be an alternative to arc/resisto-jets

Comment: I apologize in advance for an OT comment, but after seeing the iconic Echo photo all my life I only recently realized that the NASA logo was not painted onto the satellite, it appears to be just a banner that was applied for photo ops, and presumably removed before launch. Makes sense to not paint a logo on, why add unneeded weight and complicate unfurling since in space no one would see it. I also didn't realize that there were actually two satellites, Echo 1 (1960) and Echo 2 (1964). The photo is Echo 1. And they were in orbit longer than I thought, Echo 1 eight years, Echo 2 five years.

Comment: @StevePemberton ... it must have provided a solid data point on aerodynamic drag in LEO, considering the size and perfect geometry.

Comment: also related (but different): [How far from the Sun can solar power be used as a reliable energy source?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/623/12102) and also [How quickly do the Van Allen radiation belts degrade solar panels?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13637/12102) and also [At some point far from the Sun does the output of solar panels start dropping much faster than inverse square? If so, how fast?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/61786/12102)

Answer (score 6):

### Smaller, More Robust, Proven

OP's question basically includes all the information needed to show that RTGs outperform solar concentration.

The 8m concentrator OP proposes would weigh ~12 kg, per the numbers given, which is already heavier than the ~8 kg plutonium core. Whatever is used to deploy the concentrator - the pressurized gas canister, the foam to fix it in place, etc. only adds more weight.

The RTG has basically no failure modes or moving parts - plutonium produces decay heat, and the TG turns that into electric power.

In contrast, a solar concentrator would need to be deployed, which has some risk of failure. Exposure to the space environment will likely degrade the reflective properties of the concentrator, and building a larger or more robust concentrator to account for that would add to the weight.

Any maneuvers that point the concentrator away from the Sun would cause a loss of power, so presumably you'd want to add an active pointing mechanism to keep the concentrator working at all times, which would add weight and additional failure modes.

Finally, RTGs are proven. There's no new development cost, the risks are well understood, and they just work. Even if the material cost of the concentrator was zero, how many missions would it take to pay off the development cost? How does that math change if even one mission fails completely when an unexpected failure mode kills all electrical power onboard?

### Still Not Enough Power

OP states an 6m concentrator can produce a solar flux on the 0.16 square meter TG as similar to the flux as on Mercury. [This](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/mercuryfact.html) NASA fact sheet gives Mercury a solar irradiance of ~9,000 W/m<sup>2</sup>. That gives 1,440 watts of thermal energy on the TG, which is about a third of the power that the [RTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPHS-RTG) in question. So since Cassini had three RTGs, the 6m concentrator might supply about 11% of the power required by Cassini.

So you'd need a rather large concentrator to make this work.

Comment: All good points. However, the concentrator does not necessarily need independent pointing and support. It can be combined with the high gain antennae since a spherical mirror can "point" in multiple directions at the same time, depending on the location of the chosen "focus" (see Arecibo antennae design).

Comment: RTGs are incredibly reliable, but output decreases most rapidly when new, as measured from manufacturing date. The RTG needs to be sized for power requirements at the end of the spacecraft's service life (which is unexpectedly long for NASA gear in the outer solar system ... think Voyager). For instance, Pu238 RTGs loose 20% of their output in the first 18 years from manufacture. Assini took almost 7 years to arrive on station, so the RTG's best years were wasted.

Comment: Solar cells also degrade over time, about 1-2% per year [according to NASA](https://science.nasa.gov/learn/basics-of-space-flight/chapter11-3/). And a reflector will gradually degrade and grow less reflective over time as well.